# Resampling 0.7 m LiDAR (in raster already) to 10 m DEM in R?

Tags: raster, r, dem, lidar, resampling

How do I resample the 0.7 m LiDAR to 10 m DEM in R?

What are the basic rules for checking the consistency?

Comment: Didn't you ask this yesterday? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309311/resampling-0-7m-lidar-to-10m-dem-in-arcgis-desktop#comment501105_309311

Comment: @MichaelStimson [That question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309311) was re-scoped from being about ArcGIS Desktop or R to being about just ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: I see. I'd do this with GDAL_Translate -tr 10 10 unless there's a lot of images to do.

Comment: Do you have GDAL? If so, use "[gdalwarp](https://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) -tr 10 10 -r average src_dataset dst_dataset" to do a proper down sample.

Comment: What do you mean by "consistency"?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do is using `resample` from `raster` package. Two methods are available: 'bilinear' and 'nearest neighbour' (pick nearest neighbour, as suggested in [Resample binary raster to give *proportion* within new cell window](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27838/resample-binary-raster-to-give-proportion-within-new-cell-window/27849#27849)).

See the example code from `raster` package documentation:

```
# this is a sample code which you need to adapt to your specific case.
r <- raster(nrow=3, ncol=3)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
s <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
s <- resample(r, s, method='bilinear')
#par(mfrow=c(1,2))
```

In the example above, `r` is your 0.7 m LiDAR DEM, and `s` is the raster object to be resampled. Make sure `s` has the following parameters equal to `r`:

- origin (see `xmn`, `ymn` parameters). OR
- `ext` (extent, aka bounding box). If you want `r` and `s` to have the same extent (i.e., to match in their outside borders), you need to resample to a cell size multiple from 0.7 m. For example, 9.8 m. AND
- `crs` (Coordinate Reference System).

Check the `raster` function to know how to set above parameters in `s`.

Comment: The question is about aggregation, not about interpolation.

Comment: @MikeT, the question is about **resampling**, which is a method of interpolation (one interpolates within the new cell, from the previous multiple cells; but aggregation is correct as well).

Comment: A bilinear method is good for interpolation (i.e. constructing new data points within the range of a discrete set of known data points). However, bilinear is a poor choice when aggregating to a coarser resolution. See more details [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29060) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27849).

Comment: `raster::aggregate` looks like a promising approach (which I haven't used). However, it requires an integer factor, whereas 0.7 is not a factor of 10...