# Resample raster image, how to choose new resolution?

Tags: raster, gdalwarp, resolution, resampling

I know this is not a new question, and I know it depends on the context and what I would like to do with the data, but I am still finding it difficult to solve this problem in practice. And I haven't found any good answer online (*this question was marked as possible duplicate, but I do not think this is the case, so I have modified my question, I hope it is clearer now*).

**For example:** I have a [raster image](https://daac.ornl.gov/CLIMATE/guides/global_N_deposition_maps.html) of modeled atmospheric N deposition for the whole world, with a resolution of 5 by 3.75 degrees. Now I would like to resample it to a finer resolution, say with *cubic resampling* from **GDAL warp**.

[image: Atmospheric N deposition, World]

**EDIT:** 
The reason I want to do this is that I would like to estimate N deposition per country. I understand I am introducing an error when I do any resampling, however as you can see in the image, the pixels are really quite large compared to the size of an average country.

Now I could run a **zonal statistics** on a world countries vector layer, using this raster image as it is. However, I suspect that my results would be of better quality if I resample the raster image first, to a higher resolution. If I am wrong, than please let me know and I will close this question myself.

**Question:** Can you please explain what logical steps and reasoning I should follow to decide the new resolution of the raster image? The aim here is to then run a Zonal Statistics on the higher resolution raster image, with a vector layer containing country boundaries.

I would like this to be an example of how to make such a decision, I don't care so much about the answer to this specific case.

Comment: Please focus your post by including a single question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've edited the question, and split the question into two parts, is this better?

Comment: @ffgg: There's a one question per post-policy, please try to comply with it. Also, your question is rather well researchable, maybe try that first and then ask more specific questions.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, however, I still count 5 questions. This post is likely to be closed by the community unless you can focus in one question.

Comment: Thank you, I have now focused in one question, I hope this is good enough

Comment: As a general rule you cannot resample a raster to create new data. For example, you cannot resample a precipitation raster to produce more accurate localized data. Resampling to a finer resolution is usually done to align  different datasets for further analysis.

Comment: @Aaron, answered your question: the new “artificial” resolution will be based on other datasets (if they exist) if they are needed. Avoid using bilinear interpolation for resampling (prefer nearest neighbor in this case); see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27838/resample-binary-raster-to-give-proportion-within-new-cell-window/27849#27849.

Comment: I see you have marked my question as a duplicate but I don't think the answer in the linked question is very relevant. Can I edit my question further or should I open a new question?

Comment: You should edit your question and explain at the beginning why you think that it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I agree with @PolyGeo, please edit your question to indicate how yours is different from the linked duplicate. I see the answer in the duplicate as a good solution to your question.

Comment: Ok thank you all for your feedback and patience, I have edited my question further.