# Resampling 1000m resolution Aqua MODIS images to 30m resolution

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, modis, modis-reprojection-tool, pymodis

I am trying to resample the **MODIS (aqua)** image from 1000m resolution to LandSat image resolution which is of 30m for applying **ESTARTFM** technique. 
So you need to do preprocessing **(Resampling and Reprojection)** before applying the algorithm. But when i read [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/56994) it is suggested not to go from finer to coarser resolution.  So, my first question why it is not recommended secondly how to achieve the same using QGIS 3.6.
Also, I tried resampling MODIS image using [pyMODIS](http://www.pymodis.org/scripts/modis_convert.html) using the following script

```
modis_convert.py -s "( 1 )" -o outputmodis.tiff -e 32630 -g 30 MYD11A1.A2019133.h17v03.006.2019150001731.hdf
```

So, my final TIFF size increased from 2 MB to 3.4 GB. Is there something wrong I am doing here? Though When I resampled it to 500 m size increased from 2MB to 10 MB.

Comment: You increase the resolution thirtyfold and wonder why your filesize goes through the roof? You have much to learn, young padawan. Also, I doubt that increasing the resolution is that helpful, since you'll still end up with a washed out version of the 1x1 km data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your file sizes are as expected. When you go from 1000m per pixel, to 30m per pixel, you get 1111-times increase in size, which is close to what you see from 2 MB to 3.4 GB, once you also consider compression etc. The calculation is:

```
(1000 m/ 30m)^2 = 1111.1
```

It is squared due to the raster being a 2d array.

The whole point of STARFM, or ESTARTFM (a derived model), is to apply data fusion to get daily 30m data from MODIS. This means that you will get a much larger file size. The other thread that you linked to is not related to data fusion, so there, oversampling the data is not recommended, but for data fusion, such as STARFM, it is essentially the whole point.

Comment: Thanks Mikkel. I have one more question Is it possible to do the resampling of HDF using  `QGIS 3.6` or  `HDF-EOS To GeoTIFF Conversion Tool (HEG)`? I tried but couldn't find any option

Comment: In QGIS, you can use 'Raster - Warp', and set the 'Target Resolution'.

Answer (score 1):

If you have gdal, you can try `gdal_translate -outsize 3333.33% 3333.33% -r bilinear input.tif output.tif`

Comment: For data-fusion purposes, it should likely be '-r near'.

Comment: Is there any problem if i use cubic convolution. As i read it gives the smooth edges in the final output after fusion